# Warning: Illegal string offset в PHP (При использовании Android Studio)

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При попытке регистрации происходит следующая ошибка:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'user_login' in ....\db_register.php on line *32*

При этом запись в базу данных происходит в корректном виде!

Файл регистрации:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/db_functions.php';
$db = new db_functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['user_login']) && isset($_POST['user_password']) && isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['user_middle_name']) && isset($_POST['user_last_name']) && isset($_POST['user_group'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $user_login = $_POST['user_login'];
    $password = $_POST['user_password'];
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_middle_name = $_POST['user_middle_name'];
    $user_last_name = $_POST['user_last_name'];
    $user_group = $_POST['user_group'];

    // check if user is already existed with the same login
    if ($db->isUserExisted($user_login)) {
        // user already existed
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User " . $user_login . " already exists";
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $user = $db->storeUser($user_login, $password, $user_name, $user_middle_name, $user_last_name, $user_group);
        if ($user) {

            **ОШИБКА ПРОИСХОДИТ ЗДЕСЬ, ВО ВСЕХ СЛЕДУЮЩИХ ПОЛЯХ $response**

            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["user_uniqueid"];
            $response["user"]["user_login"] = $user["user_login"];
            $response["user"]["user_name"] = $user["user_name"];
            $response["user"]["user_middle_name"] = $user["user_middle_name"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Failed to store";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Fill up all fields!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: $user["user_login"] - вы пробовали дебажить? Эта ошибка возникает когда вы обращаетесь к несуществующему полю массива.

Comment: Солидарен с предыдущим оратором! :) Посмотрите через var_dump($user) , что у вас выводится там... может быть у вас $user - это объект, и обращаться к его свойствам нужно так: $user->user_login, или, может быть $user - это массив со вложенными массивами, и обращаться нужно вот так: $user[0]['user_login']... это как наиболее напрашивающиеся варианты, на деле это может быть и null или [] (пустой массив), если этого юзерлогина в базе нет, или массив объектов... короче, сначала дебажте, и если там вообще что-то сверхъестественное, тогда возвращайтесь и задавайте вопрос уже более обстоятельно :)